# How to check the presence of Particular user online/offline status through XMPP server

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I am building an app where I need to find online/offline status of only those users with whom I have exchanged messages in past. Not all the users available on the server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I want to implement the same thing. Didi you get any solution for it? If yes please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @nikBhosale I am not getting particular user's online/offline status. So what I am doing is storing all the users online/offline status in an array and filtering that array for the users I want to show status on the basis of Jabber Id.

Comment: Okay, but I guess it would be less efficient as you need to keep your array on continuous listening and editing mode. Instead maybe you can look at my answer using XMPPIQ. Also please upvote if you think it's correct way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

-You can get particular user's online/offline status using XMPPIQ
You need to create XMPPIQ with 'type get' as following

```
let query = XMLElement(name: "query", xmlns: "jabber:iq:last")
        let streamUUID = self.xmppStream.generateUUID()
        let iq = XMPPIQ(type: "get", to: XMPPJID(string: jid) , elementID: streamUUID , child: query)
        self.xmppStream.send(iq)
        return streamUUID!
```

then there is delegate method in XMPPStreamDelegate protocol named 'didReceive iq:', you need to provide handle IQ result in thi smethod as follows,

```
 func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, didReceive iq: XMPPIQ!) -> Bool {
        if iq.isResultIQ() {
            iq.lastActivitySeconds() == 0{
               print("user is online")
            }else{
               print("user is offline") 
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presences are broadcast, so you just receive them when the "happen". There are presence probes in the context of a remote server (S2S, server-to-server). But there is no polling.

Answer (score 0):

To have the presence (mentioned by Nyco) pushed to the client, you would have to subscribe to the other user's presence. It's described here: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#sub